# i have used api but having a confusion how to take base url and the parameters using retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

my api is :

https://api.domainname.com/25/SmartService.svc/GetFundslistByPANIMEI=ODY2NzQxMDMzNDQwMjQx%0A&Fund=&APKVer=NC4zMg%3D%3D%0A&pan=QUZZUE01NzE5Qg%3D%3D%0A&Adminusername=c21hcnRzZXJ2aWNl&OS=QW5kcm9pZA%3D%3D%0A&Adminpassword=a2FydnkxMjM0JTI0

And the JSON respone in the above URL is as below

```
{"Table":[{"Error_code":"0","Error_Message":"Success","EncryptionFlag":"N"}
],"Table1":[{"Fund_Id":"128","FN_FundDescription":"ABCD FUND"},{"Fund_Id":"178","FN_FundDescription":"XYZ FUND"},{"Fund_Id":"116","FN_FundDescription":"Pritham FUND"},{"Fund_Id":"118","FN_FundDescription":"Ram FUND"},{"Fund_Id":"130","FN_FundDescription":"Mannu FUND"}]}
```

I have taken baseurl as https://api.domainname/25/SmartService.svc in the mainactivity.java

Can any body tell me how to call rest of the url part in the Interface.java class as a @GET(" ");

I have generated a pojo classes also it generated into 3 classes.

1 .Example.java

```
package com.example.retrofit;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

    @SerializedName("Table")
    @Expose
    private List<Table> table = null;
    @SerializedName("Table1")
    @Expose
    private List<Table1> table1 = null;

    public List<Table> getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public void setTable(List<Table> table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public List<Table1> getTable1() {
        return table1;
    }

    public void setTable1(List<Table1> table1) {
        this.table1 = table1;
    }

}
```

2.Table.java

```
package com.example.retrofit;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Table {

    @SerializedName("Error_code")
    @Expose
    private String errorCode;
    @SerializedName("Error_Message")
    @Expose
    private String errorMessage;
    @SerializedName("EncryptionFlag")
    @Expose
    private String encryptionFlag;

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public String getEncryptionFlag() {
        return encryptionFlag;
    }

    public void setEncryptionFlag(String encryptionFlag) {
        this.encryptionFlag = encryptionFlag;
    }

}
```

3 .Table1.java
    package com.example.retrofit;

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Table1 {

    @SerializedName("Fund_Id")
    @Expose
    private String fundId;
    @SerializedName("FN_FundDescription")
    @Expose
    private String fNFundDescription;

    public String getFundId() {
        return fundId;
    }

    public void setFundId(String fundId) {
        this.fundId = fundId;
    }

    public String getFNFundDescription() {
        return fNFundDescription;
    }

    public void setFNFundDescription(String fNFundDescription) {
        this.fNFundDescription = fNFundDescription;
    }

}
```

SO please anyone help me how to take the parameters from the remaining url and to use it with querymap concept.so that i can display the json response in recyclerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should use `https://api.domainname/25/SmartService.svc` as base url. What you should do instead is:

Make the following changes:

Base URL : `https://api.domainname/`

Your "Rest of the URL Part" should be : `@GET("{numValue}/SmartService.svc")`

One Possible Approach :

```
@GET("{numValue}/SmartService.svc")
public Call<List<Example>> getExample(
   @Path("num_value") int numValue,
   @Query("GetFundslistByPANIMEI") String panImei,
   @Query("Fund") String fund,
   @Query("APKVer") String apkVer,
   @Query("pan") String pan,
   @Query("Adminusername") String adminUsername,
   @Query("Adminpassword") String adminPassword)
```

Here `{numValue}` is the value you supplied i.e. `25`.

Of course you can use `@QueryMap Map<String, String>`. Please do check the official [Retrofit Documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for more information.

NOTE: Also please make sure the return of `getExample()` is what you expect. I might have misunderstood and used `Call<List<Example>>`.

Comment: But its not working for me i have tried one more i have done a mistake in posting the URL its domainname.com not domainname

Comment: You're missing the point `domainname.com` or `domainname` has nothing to do with your problem. Change your code as I have answered and report back if any problem exists.